# Storing every individual update to the posts being updated over time?

Tags: custom-post-types, posts

Some of my posts will continue being updated over time, with new pieces of information appended. The closest real-life example I could find is [this article from The Guardian](https://www.theguardian.com/football/live/2021/may/18/brighton-v-manchester-city-premier-league-live). See how it mainly consists of the similar blocks sorted by time. Can I accomplish something similar with Wordpress?

This will give me the flexibility to:

- make every block have a permalink
- make the page structure more consistent and reusable, with an ability to dynamically change the UI to table view, list view, grid view etc.
- if a new block is added to the post as the visitor is reading it, alert them

I'm not necessarily building a news outlet though, instead as I'm researching a topic, I want to store every step as an individual building block.

- Simply updating a post won't work, because it doesn't enforce the structure
- The closest idea I came up with is to have these blocks actually be individual posts, attach them to a category, and make that category act like a post – but this seriously feels like fighting the framework

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: This question is really a matter of opinion, so it's not necessarily appropriate for this site. That being said, your suggestion of each block being an individual post absolutely seems like the right direction to me, since it does everything you want.

Comment: @JacobPeattie Hi and thank you for your feedback. Sorry, I disagree with your statement on the question being opinion-based. Unless I'm missing something, I believed I made it obvious and explicit I was asking for someone's advice and experience. What has made you think I wasn't?

Comment: Different users are going to have different opinions on how to implement something like this. Hence opinion-based. This site is intended for development (i.e. coding) questions that can have a definitive or near-definitive answer. It's not suited for sourcing feedback or advice.

Answer (score 0):

One option could be to create a private (*show in Dashboard, hide from front-end*) custom post type (*e.g. `article_section`*). You would relate these sections to a single post (*Article*) with the cpt's `post_parent` property so that the sections would become the children of the post. WP doesn't really care if the child posts have different post type than the parent post. Querying parent-children relation (*one-to-many?*) is easy and efficient.

Then create a custom dynamic block which, when added to a post, would query the post's child section cpts and list them in publish date order (*newest first*). This list can then be manipulated with js to, for example, change the layout. Additionally you can create an ajax call to WP REST (*or admin-ajax, if you prefer the old way*) to periodically check for new child sections.